# table name altered after importing a mysql database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a MySql database in phpmyadmin. While I am successfully able to do that but the name of the tables are a little altered. For example, in the original database I have a table named AgeGroup. But when I am importing it in another machine it is changed to agegroup. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Some filesystems are case sensitive, some case insensitive. That's most likely the source of your issue. What operating systems are you working on?

Comment: I am working on Windows. I am importing from a remote server. Don't know the operating system of that server. Could be linux.